# Django Templates can not access to context

Tags: python, django, listview, templates

I checked all the questions and answers in this site, but could not find a solution. I am new in Django, trying to develop a storage model and stucked already in the ListView.

part of my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from Storage.models import Storage
from django.http import HttpResponse

class StorageListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Storage
    print(Storage.objects.order_by('-barcode'))
    template_name = 'Storage/Storagelist.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
       return Storage.objects.order_by('-barcode')
```

I add print statement to check whether I reach the model and 
everyting seems normal:

```
<QuerySet [<Storage: 123>, <Storage: 122>, <Storage: 121>]>
```

However, I can not reach the context from the template file 'Storagelist.html':

```
<h3>trial</h3>
{% if storage_list %} <h3>trial</h3> {% endif %}
```

Just to check access via url configurations, I added 'trial' at the beginning of the template and it also seems normal. I also tried to use context_object_name, but did not help either. Somehow, I can not reach to ListView context data from the template.

My versions of applications are as follows:
Django      2.0.3
Python      3.6.1
Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Your model is `Storage`, so `storage_list` should be available in the template context. You could try adding [`{% debug %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug), or you might find the [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) useful for problems like this.

Comment: python raise any exception? Can you put the console output?

Comment: this code shows storage_list is null, I guess  {% if storage_list %} <h3>OK</h3> {% endif %} . I have already installed django debug toolbar, however, could not find how I can check the query data...

Comment: Performing system checks...

<QuerySet [<Storage: 123>, <Storage: 122>, <Storage: 121>]>
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 30, 2018 - 02:08:42
Django version 2.0.3, using settings 'FirstProto.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Answer (score 0):

In a `ListView` I believe the objects will populate into the template as `object_list`. You might consider using [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts) to make the template context variable human readable (and also match what you are expecting). In other words, try adding `context_object_name = storage_list` to your view.

Comment: I have already tried context_object_name = 'storage_list' but did not solve the problem:

Comment: Got it, I would follow the advice from @Alasdair and enable debug on the template to see what variables are being passed.

Comment: It is a big list but the first part is as follows:                                {}{'block': \n
, , STORAGE PROTOTYPE\n '>, , \n '>, , \n
'>, , \n
'>, , , ]>, \n '>]>}{'view': }{}{'DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS': {'DEBUG': 10, 'ERROR': 40, 'INFO': 20, 'SUCCESS': 25, 'WARNING': 30}, 'csrf_token': , 'debug': True, 'messages': , 'perms': , 'request': , 'sql_queries': . at 0x0000028D938A5BF8>, 'user': >}{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True} {'FirstProto': , 'FirstProto.settings': , 'FirstProto.urls': , 'FirstProto.views': , 'FirstProto.wsgi': ,

Comment: Is it possible that I face with a name clash? There are lots of 'storage_list' in the variables... How can I possibly refer to the context explicitly?

Comment: Can you maybe make a gist of the debug output? (obviously stripping anything sensitive out)